How to use ProtectedSessionStorage with a Serilog enricher?
I have an enricher that needs to use the protected session storage to get the user info:
public class UserEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    private const string UsernamePropertyName = "Username";

    private readonly ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage;

    public UserEnricher (
        ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage)
    {
        this.sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
    }

    public async void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        var userName = await sessionStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("UsernameKey");
        var userNameProperty = propertyFactory.CreateProperty(UsernamePropertyName, userName);
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(userNameProperty);
    }
}

And the enricher is set up as a transient service and added to the serilog configuration on startup.
However I am getting:

Cannot resolve 'Serilog.Enrichers.UserEnricher' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage.ProtectedSessionStorage'.

Is accessing the session storage even possible in such a case?

Have you tried configuring Serilog to use scoped services like builder.Services.AddScoped();? Are SessionEnricher and UserEnricher two different enrichers? And can you describe how you configured them?

@YuningDuan Typo the class names. I did the change with regards from transient to scoped and now I get the error: Cannot resolve scoped service 'UserEnricher' from root provider.
